# Generalized quasi-perfect numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, perfect-numbers

A number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is called [quasi-perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiperfect_number) if $\sigma(n) = 2n+1$, where $\sigma$ is the sum of divisors function. It is known that if $n$ is quasi-perfect, then it must be the square of an odd integer (an oddly beautiful Putnam problem from the 1970s). To date no number is known to be quasi-perfect.

My question concerns the existence of 'generalized' quasi-perfect numbers, or rather, let $a,b \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ be fixed integers, and call an integer $n$ $(a,b)$ quasi-perfect if it satisfies $\sigma(n) = an+b$.

Are there any known values of $a,b$ for which the number of $(a,b)$ quasi-perfect numbers are known to be infinite?

Comment: I wondered about this a while ago and __dblues__ had some nice preliminary observations in the very last post of this AoPS thread: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=83696

Comment: Primes. You might consider negative b, otherwise the answer may turn out to be no.

Answer (score 6):

See the abstract of my PhD thesis, "Generalised quasiperfect numbers", Bulletin Australian Math. Soc., 27 (1983), 153-156, where I consider numbers $n$ with $\sigma(n) = 2n + k^2$, $k$ odd, $(n,k)=1$.

Graeme Cohen

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow, Graeme!

Answer (score 4):

Clearly, if $n=p$ whith $p$ being prime answers the question. $\sigma(p)=p+1$ which proves the case for $a=b=1$

Comment: Or, more generally, if you take any $m$, then $n=pm$ with $p$ coprime to $m$ gives $\sigma(pm)=(p+1)\sigma(m)$, which means $a=b=\sigma(m)$ works.

Comment: Sorry James, but that doesn't work.  (Try m=5 and various p.)

Comment: @JamesCranch Can you give a numeric example? You need $\sigma(pm)=a p m + b$ and your example doesn't appear of this form.

Comment: Sorry: you're right, I'm wrong!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I can only give some *non-answers* to this question.

In the case $b=0$, I believe the answer is still unknown. There are some references in Sandor, et al, *The Handbook of Number Theory* starting on page 105. In particular, the best that appears to be known is the following upper bound:
$$
\#\{n \le x | \sigma(n) = a n\} \le c x^{c' \log \log \log x/ \log \log x}
$$
for all $a \in \mathbb{Q}$. ($c,c'$ are independent of $a$.)

I believe Konstantinos's example could be extended slightly: if $a=1$ and $b\neq 1$, then the number of solutions should be finite.

Answer (score 3):

For similar questions searching OEIS might help.

Trying $\sigma(n) = 2 n + 2$ returns [A088831 Numbers n whose abundance sigma(n)-2n=+2](https://oeis.org/A088831)

A comment in the sequence:

> If $2^n-3$ is prime (n is a term of A050414) then $2^{n-1}(2^n-3)$ is
>   in the sequence.

I supposes it plausible that there infinitely many primes of the form
$2^n-3$.

**Added**

There are provable solutions for $a=2$ and for $a=k$ when k-multiperfect
numbers $\sigma(m) = k m$ exist.

Let $m$ be perfect number ($\sigma(m)=2m$) and $p$ a prime coprime to $m$.

$\sigma( m p ) = 2  m ( p + 1 ) = 2 m p + 2 m$

$a=2, b=2 m$.

For k-multiperfect numbers $m$, $a=k, b= k m$.

Comment: That seems to differ from what I was trying to do, insofar as it's actually correct.

Comment: @JamesCranch maybe your method will work for prime $p$ and $a$ rational (depending on sigma), yet the question is about integer $a$.

Answer (score 3):

The related equation
$$\sigma(n) = An + B(n)$$
where $B(n)$ "is a function that may depend on properties of $n$" is considered in the paper [Variations on Euclid’s Formula for Perfect Numbers](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL13/Hasler/hasler2.pdf) by Farideh Firoozbakht and Maximilian F. Hasler, published in the Journal of Integer Sequences.